# How to you do a rolling sum in Pandas where the index is descending?

Tags: pandas

I want to calculate a trailing rolling window on a dataframe that is sorted in descending order.

For example let

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}, index=[f'20{i}' for i in range(21, 14, -1)])

>>> df  
        A
2021    1
2020    2
2019    3
2018    4
2017    5
2016    6
2015    7
```

How can I neatly calculate the mean of the last two years? Ie. a neater version of:

```
ans = df.iloc[::-1].rolling(2).mean().iloc[::-1]
>>> ans
           A
2021    1.50
2020    2.50
2019    3.50
2018    4.50
2017    5.50
2016    6.50
2015    NaN
```

I implemented this for now:

```
def irolling(s:pd.Series, aggfunc, **kwargs)->pd.Series:
    return s.iloc[::-1].rolling(**kwargs).agg(aggfunc).iloc[::-1]

df.pipe(irolling, aggfunc='mean', window=2)
```

And I know I could register `irolling` to the pandas API as show [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the rolling average going forward and then shift up the result by one row.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}, index=[f'20{i}' for i in range(21, 14, -1)])
ans = df.rolling(2).mean().shift(-1)
ans
```

This returns the same as your attempt

```
        A
2021    1.5
2020    2.5
2019    3.5
2018    4.5
2017    5.5
2016    6.5
2015    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I like this, I will use the `irolling` function as defined in my question. It seems easier for me to extend the code to other window types, variable sizes, etc..